# How can I round up values in PHP

Tags: php

I want to round up the values in `PHP`. please suggest me any function how to implement the values in round.

example how to convert it round as below:

```
803   --> 800 

791.5 --> 790

811   --> 810

845.7 --> 850

850.6 --> 860

900.5 --> 900

1016.9 --> 1020
```

Comment: Have you searched on google ?

Comment: You're not "rounding up", you're [rounding](http://cstl.syr.edu/fipse/decunit/roundec/roundec.htm).... except for `850.6 --> 860` which (surely) should become `850`..... and the answer is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php]

Comment: What is rounding up here `803 --> 800` and `811 --> 810` ?

Comment: Your "rounding" is not consistent. It is unclear what you are asking for because you don't describe clearly how your desired results are obtained.

Comment: This one doesn't match the others 850.6 --> 860 as far as pattern goes.

Comment: What is the logic in: `850.6 --> 860` `900.5 --> 900`? These make no sense whatsoever compared to eachother.

Comment: Please be clear in your rounding pattern, It doesn't makes any sense as the above user's pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 803->800 use round(803,-1), for 900.5->900 use floor(900.5).

for more examples you better take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: `round(900.5)` would return 901.

Comment: `round(850.6,-1);` would return 850...

Answer (score 0):

**Since there is nothing in common with the examples**, I'll do them 1 by 1 for you:

```
echo floor(803/100)*100; --> 800

echo floor(791.5/10)*10; --> 790

echo floor(811/10)*10; --> 810

echo ceil(845.7/10)*10; --> 850

echo ceil(850.6/10)*10; --> 860

echo floor(900.5/100)*100; --> 900 // echo floor(900.5/10)*10 works as well

echo ceil(1016.9/10)*10; --> 1020
```

Just in case you dont get it: **You make the number smaller, to get the floor/ceil function to get the proper result divided by 10 after using the floor/ceil function, you multiply by 10.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it mathematically, This is how you can do a follow...

845.7 % 10 = 5.7(reminder)

let, 
you want to round up 900.5;

```
<?php
$value = round(900.5);
$roundedValue = 0;

if(($value % 10) > 5){ 
        $roundedValue = intval($value / 10) * 10 + 10 ; 
     }else{
         $roundedValue = intval($value / 10) * 10;
    }
    echo "The value is: ".$roundedValue;
?>
```

Then $roundedValue is what you want! Hope this help. Best of luck.

Comment: You'll get a syntax error ;)

Comment: Ops, actually I wan't serious about the php but the mathematical part. By the way, Its should work now.